# Get the property on Validation.Error event

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, binding

Is it possible to get the binding for which fired the event: `Validation.Error`?

For example: I signed up for this event in a text box:

```
 <TextBox Validation.Error="My_Error" Text="{Binding MyProp,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
```

The event runs when there is a validation error and reaches the following function:

```
private void My_Error(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
{
  //Here I want to get the property for which fired the event (MyProp). Is it possible?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do it:

```
        viewmodel Vm = (e.Error.BindingInError as BindingExpression).DataItem as viewmodel ;// Take viem model from data item. (I think that data item is the binding of the window - not sure)

        string propName= (e.Error.BindingInError as BindingExpression).ParentBinding.Path.Path;// The path is the prop name

        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop = Vm.GetType().GetProperty(propName);// Here the prop

        var valProp = prop.GetValue(Vm, null);//Here the value
```